# Здравствуйте! нужна помощь с -webkit-!

Tags: html

есть задание : Задача: есть два блока, каждый из которых имеет три блока. Превратите внутренние блоки ( itemкласс) в гибкие элементы. Первый внешний (с firstклассом) должен вести себя как элемент блока, второй (с secondклассом) - как элемент inline-block.

Чтобы правильно выполнить эту задачу, используйте -webkit-префикс перед значением displayсвойства.

вот код :

```
          .first{
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .first .item {
            border: 2px solid green;
        }

        .second .item {
            border: 2px solid blue;
        }

        .item {
            margin-right: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="first">
        <div class="item">Div1</div>
        <div class="item">Div2</div>
        <div class="item">Div3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="item">Div4</div>
        <div class="item">Div5</div>
        <div class="item">Div6</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.first{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.second{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.first .item {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.second .item {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.item:first-child{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="first">
        <div class="item">Div111111111111111</div>
        <div class="item">Div2</div>
        <div class="item">Div3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="item">Div4</div>
        <div class="item">Div5</div>
        <div class="item">Div6</div>
    </div>
</body>
```